# Computing the expectation value of a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, expectation, stochastic-calculus, conditional-expectation, stochastic-analysis

I have a stochastic differential equation for which I have solved the process *X$_t$*. The SDE is as follows:

$$
dX_t = \left( r\mu X_t + \frac{r(r-1)} 2 \sigma^2 X_t \right) \, dt + r\sigma X_t\,dB_t,
$$

in which $X_0 = x$ and $x > 0$.

Here is what I did to solve for the process $X_t$:

$$ dX_t=\left(r\mu+\frac{1}{2}r(r-1)\sigma^2\right)X_t\,dt+r\sigma X_t \,dB_t $$
Using Ito's lemma
$$d(\ln X_t)=\frac{1}{X_t}dX_t+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{-1}{X_t^2}\right) \, d[X_t,X_t]$$
and then I solved as follows
$$d(\ln X_t)=\left(r\mu+\frac{1}{2}r(r-1)\sigma^2\right)\,dt+r\sigma \, dB_t-\frac{1}{2}r^2\sigma^2 \, dt$$

$$d(\ln X_t)=\left(r\mu-\frac{1}{2}r\sigma^2\right)\,dt+r\sigma \, dB_t$$

$$\ln X_t-\ln x_0=\left(r\mu-\frac{1}{2}r\sigma^2\right)t+r\sigma \, B_t$$

$$X_t=x_0\exp\left(\left[r\mu-\frac{1}{2}r\sigma^2\right]t+r\sigma \, B_t\right)$$

If I have $f(x) = (x - K)^2$ for some $K > 0$, how do I compute the expectation $\operatorname{E}[f (X_t)]$? Can someone please show me how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Ultimately, you are asking for $E(e^{cB_t})$, for various values of $c$ and $t$. No idea to compute this?

Comment: No, I am completely lost. Can you please show me how to do this?

Comment: You are manipulating solutions of stochastic differential equations but simple characteristics of centered normal distributions elude you? How is that?

Answer (score 2):

$$\mathbb{E}[f(X_t)]=\mathbb{E}[X_t^2-2KX_t+K^2]=\mathbb{E}[X_t^2]-2K\,\mathbb{E}[X]+K^2\tag 1$$
set $Y=\ln X_t$, therefore
$$Y=\ln X_t\sim N\left( \ln x_0+\left( \mu -\frac{1}{2} r\sigma^2 \right)t\,\,,\,\,r^2 \sigma^2t \right)$$
We have 
$$\mathbb{E}[X_t^2]=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{2\ln X_t}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{2Y}\right]=M_{Y}(2)=\exp\left(2\mu_Y+\frac 12\sigma_Y^2(2)^2\right)$$
Indeed
$$\mathbb{E}[X_t^2]=\exp\left(2\ln x_0+\left( 2\mu -r\sigma^2 \right) t+2r^2\sigma^2t\right) \tag 2$$
similarly
$$\mathbb{E}[X_t]=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\ln X_t}\right] = \mathbb{E} \left[e^Y\right]=M_Y(1)=\exp\left(\mu_Y+\frac 12\sigma_Y^2(1)^2\right)$$
in other words
$$\mathbb{E}[X_t]=\exp\left(\ln x_0+\left( \mu -\frac{1}{2}r \sigma^2 \right) t+\frac{1}{2}r^2\sigma^2t\right) \tag 3$$
$(1)$,$(2)$ and $(3)$
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X_t)]=x_0^2\exp\left(\left( 2\mu -r\sigma^2 \right) t +2r^2\sigma^2t\right) -2x_0 K\,\exp\left(\left( \mu -\frac{1}{2}r \sigma^2 \right)t+\frac{1}{2}r^2\sigma^2t\right)+K^2$$

Comment: @Michael Hardy So thanks Micheal :-)